# Laptop battery suddenly goes from 0 to 100 and vice versa

Tags: laptop, battery, power

My lenovo(ideapad 510) laptop's battery behaves strange. It is a new battery. The battery level was 100% when i unplugged the adapter. Shortly the laptop was closed suddenly and didn't work without adapter. So i plugged adapter and turned on the laptop. The system was opened but battery level indicator showed 0%. When the level reached 6%(in 30 minutes which is strange and it was saying 10 hours to be full) i unplugged the adapter, laptop didn't shutdown. I closed the laptop with a normal way. When i restarted the laptop again without the adapter(not plugged-in), the battery level was %98 percent. So the same thing happened again, laptop shut down suddenly after 2 minutes running. I restarted again with adapter, the battery level was 5% and in a very short time it became 100%(it was just jumped from 5 to 100).I use fedora and windows same time (dual os). Here is the before and after information of battery which i took it in fedora: *(By the way if you look the icon-name below, you will see they are different which i think it is awkward)*

*I checked the adapter's output voltage it is around 20 volts as it says on the adapter*

**BEFORE**

```
 native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                L15L2PB4
  serial:               9001
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 25 Sep 2023 01:42:50 PM EDT (27 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              1.77 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         34.94 Wh
    energy-full-design:  34.96 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.193 W
    voltage:             8.175 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          5%
    capacity:            99.9428%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1695663770  5.000   charging
    1695663740  0.000   unknown
  History (rate):
    1695663770  1.193   charging
    1695663740  0.000   unknown
```

**AFTER**

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                L15L2PB4
  serial:               9001
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 25 Sep 2023 02:06:57 PM EDT (28 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              34.94 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         34.94 Wh
    energy-full-design:  34.96 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.801 W
    voltage:             8.171 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            99.9428%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

Comment: google thinks that model is from 2017/18. Is it still on its original battery? If so, that would be prime suspect.

Comment: Such cases almost always mean a bad battery that can't fully charge itself and its readings are false.

Comment: @Tetsujin No i changed recently since old one wasn't charging.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the comment. This could be the problem.

Comment: Since this is a new battery, you could try to [calibrate your battery](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration). If this fails, I hope the battery is still under warranty.